# How do I convert this second order differential equation to two first order differential equations?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, derivatives

The equation is $$m{\ddot x} + kx + g\sinθ = 0.$$

I know I have to convert it to the form ${\dot y}_1 = y_2$ and ${\dot y}_2 = \text{something}$.

However I am very inexperienced and very confused on how to find $y_1$ and $y_2$ from this initial equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's pose $\dot{x} = v$ (i.e. velocity). Then:

$$\begin{cases}
m \dot{v} + kx + g\sin\theta = 0\\
\dot{x} = v
\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}
\dot{v} = -\frac{k}{m}x - \frac{g}{m}\sin\theta\\
\dot{x} = v.
\end{cases}$$

Maybe, further calculation can be done for $\theta$. But if you don't specify its meaning, then these just are meaningless suppositions.

Comment: θ is an arbitrary, constant angle, that represents the angle above horizontal for a slanted plane. I am not experienced enough to know if that will affect the solution to the linear system.

Comment: @erics: The value of the parameter $\theta$ certainly affects the solution set: If $\sin \theta = 0$, the system is homogeneous, and in particular $x(t) = 0$ is a solution (this makes good intuitive sense in terms of the physical system, too). If not, the system is not homogeneous and $x(t) = 0$ is not a solution.

Comment: is there any relationship between $\theta$ and $x$? I mean, can I write $\theta$ as a function of $x$ (or vice versa)? If not, my answer is complete.

Comment: @the_candyman No, there is no relationship. Your answer is correct, thank you!